# Directory directive for directory outside doc root - best practice

Tags: apache-2.2, security, permissions, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a virtual host which has access to a directory outside of its document root.  In the config for this host I specify the directory directive to allow access to this directory.

```
<Directory /path/to/shared/>
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny 
allow from all  
</Directory>
```

The kind of files in this directory are things like images, ssi, facebook apps and some php scripts.

My question is, is this directive secure enough or do i need to add anything else?

Also, what is the ideal permissions for /shared

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the webserver's perspective it is fine. Next step would be to check the directory permissions and set them accordingly (restrict access to it for the webserver process owner).

**Update**: Not sure if you really need `AllowOverride All` as this can hit you in the face with a .htaccess-file inside the directory. I'd suggest you read up [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) to figure out what you really need. If you don't need .htaccess at all, just set it to `AllowOverride None`